# Populating a page with content from post custom fields

Tags: posts, custom-field, pages, list

I'm doing up a blog at the moment where each post is accompanied by the name of a song. Adding the songs to the posts is fairly easily done via custom fields.

However, I also need to have a page which lists all the songs in one place. Can this be done without using a plugin? If so, how? (And if not, then what's the best plugin to use to do it?)

Thanks.

Comment: It can be difficult to understand how this place works, and politeness costs nothing. Consider going easy on the non-ninjas from time to time.

Comment: i said "please" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using shortcode, as this'll easily allow you embed the song list anywhere in your content, in any page or post.

**UPDATE:** I got a little carried away, and ended up with this!

```
function song_list_shortcode( $attrs )
{
    $r = ( object )wp_parse_args( $attrs, array(
        'format' => '%post_title - %link',
        'link'   => '%song_key_name',
        'key'    => 'song_key_name'
    ) );

    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => $r->key ) ), 'nopaging' => true, 'update_post_term_cache' => false ) );
    if ( !$query->have_posts() )
        return '';

    $meta_keys = array();
    foreach ( array( 'format', 'link' ) as $type ) {
        // find meta keys
        if ( !preg_match_all( '#%([a-z0-9_-]+)#', $r->$type, $_keys ) )
            continue;

        $_keys = array_flip( $_keys[1] );
        unset( $_keys['post_title'], $_keys['link'] ); // don't want these, not meta keys

        $meta_keys = $meta_keys + $_keys; // add new keys on to meta key stack
    }

    if ( !empty( $meta_keys ) )
        $meta_keys = array_keys( $meta_keys );

    $output = '<ul class="songs">';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        $format = $r->format;
        $link = $r->link;

        if ( !empty( $meta_keys ) ) {
            // grab all meta data in one swoop (should be cached from query)
            $meta_data = get_post_custom( $query->post->ID );

            // swap out all meta key names with their actual value!
            foreach ( $meta_keys as $key ) {

                // using get_post_custom(), all meta data values are arrays
                if ( isset( $meta_data[ $key ][0] ) )
                    $value = esc_html( $meta_data[ $key ][0] );
                else
                    $value = ''; // meta key not found, so replace with blank

                list( $format, $link ) = str_replace( "%$key", $value, array( $format, $link ) );
            }
        }

        // swap out %post_title with actual post title
        list( $format, $link ) = str_replace( '%post_title', get_the_title(), array( $format, $link ) );

        // swap out %link in $format with actual $link
        $output .= '<li>' . str_replace( '%link', '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $link . '</a>', $format ) . '</li>';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'song-list', 'song_list_shortcode' );
```

You can use it like so;

```
[song-list format="%post_title - %link - %song_date_meta_key"]
// The post title - <a href="/post/">Song Name</a> - Song Date
```

See how using `%` indicates a meta key, which'll get swapped out with the value at run-time.

Also note that `%post_title` and `%link` are two special parameters that get swapped with the post title and anchor link, respectively.

You can also format the contents of the link text in the same way;

```
[song-list link="Date: %song_date_meta_key"]
// Post Title <a href="/post/">Date: Song Date</a>
```

Finally, the `key` attribute controls which posts are retrieved.

```
[song-list key="song_name"]
// Retrieves all posts with the meta key 'song_name'
```

I'd recommend replacing the hard-coded defaults at the beginning of the function with your most often used parameters.

Comment: Hi TheDeadMedic, thanks for that, it seems to be what I'm after. Is there any way to put the title of the post into the `<li>` before the song name? I tried with `the_title` but it ain't working...

Comment: You want `get_the_title()` - see revised answer.

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks. Aaaand... one last thing. :) Is there a way to output _another_ custom field in the same `<li>`? Say, to include the name of the band the song is by, or the date it was released, assuming that they're available as separate custom fields accompanying the posts?

Thanks!

Comment: So like, `<li>TITLE - [SONG NAME LINK] - DATE</li>`? Would you want to control what appears through the shortcode (for example, `[song-list show="name,date"]), or just hardcode it in the function?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm after. If it could be included in the shortcode (and so could be easily edited or expanded in future) that would be best, but I could live with it being hardcoded in the function.

Comment: @snthr Check my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks again, TheDeadMedic. I haven't had a chance yet to see if it all works, but once I get a bit of free time I'll let you know. :)

Comment: Hi again, TheDeadMedic. I'm trying to get this to work at the moment and running in to some snags (I'm a PHP noob, more or less).

How exactly do I replace the hard-coded defaults at the beginning of the function with my most often used parameters? I have, let's say, three custom fields, called 'Song Title', 'Song date' and 'Artist link' (or something like that -- they may change a bit). How do I slot them in here?

Thanks again.

Comment: Let me know the custom field you want to use to search for posts & the default format of the list (for example, `[Song Title] - [Link] ([Song Date])`, making sure the words in `[]` match the name of the custom field.

Comment: I'll probably wrap the info in a table, so it would be something like:

`<tr>
<td>[Song Title]</td>
<td>[Song date]</td>
<td>[Artist link]</td>
</tr>`

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, but I'd have to change the code to deal with tables (it outputs a list currently). Also not sure how well WordPress deals with HTML in shortcode... Perhaps it might be best to take out the attribute arguments, and just use the shortcode as it is (`[song-list]`), with the parameters set inside the function.